# Function to create or update a table in migration

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm new to ASP.NET Core Web API and I don't know if this is a simple one but:

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core Web API project and I need to add a new table to the database. There are already existing tables in the database as well. However, I'm not seeing any migration folders in the directory of the project application nor is there a `MigrationHistory` in the database so I think the tables where created in the SSMS itself. I created a new model named `SampleNewTable1` and I've also added it to the existing `DbContext` named `DataContext`.

When I ran `Add-Migration NewMigration -Context DataContext`, it created a new folder `Migrations` in the project that included my `NewMigration` file and a `DataContextModelSnapshot`.

When I ran `Update-Database -Context DataContext`

It produces this error:

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): There is already an object named 'SampleExistingTable1' in the database.
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean isAsync, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, String methodName)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1 migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
ClientConnectionId:<ID>
Error Number:2714,State:6,Class:16
There is already an object named 'SampleExistingTable1' in the database.
```

The `NewMigration` file contains this block of code:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

#nullable disable

namespace SampleApp.Migrations
{
    public partial class InitialMigration : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "SampleExistingTable1",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    DataReceived = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                    Transfered = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_SampleExistingTable1", x => x.Id);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "SampleExistingTable2",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    DataReceived = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                    Transfered = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_SampleExistingTable2", x => x.Id);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "SampleNewTable1",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    DataReceived = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                    Transfered = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_SampleNewTable1", x => x.Id);
                });
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "SampleExistingTable1");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "SampleExistingTable2");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "SampleNewTable1");
        }
    }
}
```

The `Snapshot` contains this auto-generated code:

```
// <auto-generated />
using System;
using SampleApp.Contexts;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueConversion;

#nullable disable

namespace SampleApp.Migrations
{
    [DbContext(typeof(DataContext))]
    partial class DataContextModelSnapshot : ModelSnapshot
    {
        protected override void BuildModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
#pragma warning disable 612, 618
            modelBuilder
                .HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "6.0.6")
                .HasAnnotation("Relational:MaxIdentifierLength", 128);

            SqlServerModelBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityColumns(modelBuilder, 1L, 1);

            modelBuilder.Entity("SampleApp.Models.SampleNewTable1", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<int>("Id")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    SqlServerPropertyBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityColumn(b.Property<int>("Id"), 1L, 1);

                    b.Property<string>("DataReceived")
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                    b.Property<int?>("Transfered")
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    b.HasKey("Id");

                    b.ToTable("SampleNewTable1", (string)null);
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("SampleApp.Models.SampleExistingTable1", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<int>("Id")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    SqlServerPropertyBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityColumn(b.Property<int>("Id"), 1L, 1);

                    b.Property<string>("DataReceived")
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                    b.Property<int?>("Transfered")
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    b.HasKey("Id");

                    b.ToTable("SampleExistingTable1", (string)null);
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("SampleApp.Models.SampleExistingTable2", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<int>("Id")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    SqlServerPropertyBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityColumn(b.Property<int>("Id"), 1L, 1);

                    b.Property<string>("DataReceived")
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                    b.Property<int?>("Transfered")
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    b.HasKey("Id");

                    b.ToTable("SampleExistingTable2", (string)null);
                });
#pragma warning restore 612, 618
        }
    }
}
```

How do I add a condition to not simply add or update tables depending if it:

1. Exists, without new changes to it's properties. Do Nothing
2. Exists, with new changes to it's properties. Update
3. Does not exist. Add

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason for adding the tables to the database using EntityFramework versus the same way that all previous tables were created (i.e., SSMS)?

I've used the Migrations in previous projects and they prove quite useful for code-first implementations where the project was new and the schemas were defined by my code, but I've learned that often projects that are utilizing existing databases may find it easier to continue their management of tables and schemas through DBAs.

Could you perhaps provide some additional context as to your required usage of migrations using EntityFramework?

Comment: I have multiple properties I need to add which I think would be easier if I did it in code. I don't have much experience creating tables and fields using SSMS or any other DBAs.

Comment: So are you trying to add columns to an existing table? That may get complicated with EntityFramework especially if you already have records in a table that has keys and or non-null required columns. Migrations allow you to quickly create and drop tables, but generally this would happen early in a project where you don’t necessarily have existing data populated. That way you can structure and restructure the tables as directed by a code-first requirement. Could you give more detail on your specific use case?

Comment: Currently, I'm trying to add a new model to a new table. But my attempt at migration failed due to the fact it's also migrating my existing models to the existing tables. I just need the migration to add a condition to disregard the other tables. I thought of deleting the table creation statements altogether, but I feel that it should just leave it be if it detects it already exists similar to what Laravel or Django is doing in migration.

Answer (score 0):

You could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/existing-database?redirectedfrom=MSDN) related with working with existing database(Notice it was for EF6 not EFCore)

For EFCore ,you could try as below:
1,create Entities and Dbcontext accroding to your current db

2,run `add-migration` then comment all codes in `UP` method in migration file like:

[image]

3,run `update-database`

4,modify the entities and dbcontext accroding to your requirement

5,run `add-migration` and `update-database` again

You could also try to scaffold dbcontext & entities follow this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli)